# Find the norm of the operator $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $T(x,y)=(x+2y,2x+y)$. Using lagrange multiplier theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $T: H \to K$ be a linear operator. Define the operator norm of T as $|\|T|\|=\,sup_{\|x\|=1} \frac{||T(x)\|_K}{\|x\|_H}$.

Find the norm of the operator $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $T(x,y)=(x+2y,2x+y)$. Hint: Use the Lagrange multiplier theorem.

I know that the Lagrange multiplier theorem is

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\triangledown f(x,y) & = \lambda \triangledown g(x,y) \\
g(x,y) & =k\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: You've already written $\sup_{||\mathbf x||_H = 1}$. If that doesn't make the function $||\mathbf x||_H$ with $k=1$ a good candidate for $g$ in your Lagrange multiplier method, then I don't know what would.

Comment: So we say that $g=\|x\|$ and $f=\|Tx\|$?

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. To be strict, we have $f(x) = \frac{||Tx||_K}{||x||_H}$, but we're only interested in input where $||x||_H = 1$, so the denominator can be ignored.

Comment: Now my question is we have $f=\|Tx\|=|\lambda | \cdot \|x\|=\|\lambda x \|=\lambda g$. Can we say that $Tx=\lambda x$?

Comment: Also how to a take the gradient of a norm?

Comment: $||T\mathbf x||_K = \sqrt{(x+2y)^2 + (2x+y)^2}$. That's what you're taking the gradient of.

Comment: Better to maximize $\|T\mathbf x\|^2$, instead, subject to the constraint $\|\mathbf x\|^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if the Lagrange multiplier method is required. If not write $T$ as a $2×2$-matrix and determine its eigenvalues. Then the largest absolute value is the norm of $T$.

Comment: This advice is very special: Without a symmetric matrix, it is not correct.

Comment: So I have $\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 2 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{vmatrix}=(1-\lambda)^2-4=0 \iff \lambda^2-3\lambda -3=0 \Rightarrow \lambda = 3, -1$. Then norm operator is 3?

Comment: Your result is correct but I think there is a typo in your equation after the $⟺$ sign. Note that $1-λ=±2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are rightt but here it is symmetric. If not the situation can be more complicated as discussed in the first chapter of Kato's "Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators".

Comment: For future reference, the neat fact is that for any linear map $A\colon \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$, the norm $\|A\|$ is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^\top A$.

Comment: A convenient expression